# Deleting datagridview row without deleting duplicates

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview with data, one column (EmployeeID) has the same value because it can occur more than once, I have a delete button which when clicked it deletes all the rows which has the EmployeeID 1 lets say. Is it possible to make it work so that it only deletes the row that I have selected other than it deleting all rows with a particular value.

I have the code here:

```
Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
        'check for the selected item in the list
        If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            If Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim intemployeeno As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("EmployeeID").Value
                'open connection if not already opened
                If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    cnn.Open()
                End If
                'delete data
                Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
                cmd.Connection = cnn
                'cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM attendance " & intemployeeno
                cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM attendance WHERE employeeID=" & intemployeeno
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                'refresh data
                Me.refreshdata()
                'Display pop up alert before deleting row of data
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Select 1 row before you hit Delete")
                'close connection
                cnn.Close()

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Thanks

Next part of code

Public Class Form4

```
Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

'open connection to database

Private Sub refreshdata()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection
        cnn.Open()
    End If
    'create new data and insert the data values
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT TestNumber as [TestNumber], EmployeeID as [EmployeeID], " & _
                                    "firstname as [FirstName], lastname as [LastName], date as [Date], holiday as [Holiday], halfday as [HalfDay], other as [Other], sick as [Sick], unpaidholiday as [UnpaidHoliday], daystaken as [DaysTaken], datefrom as [DateFrom], dateto as [DateTo] " & _
                                    "FROM Attendance ORDER BY FirstName", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'fill data into datatable
    da.Fill(dt)
    'offer data to be placed in datagridview
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    'close connection
    cnn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd hope so. Update your WHERE to add additional parameters so that you only delete 1 row as to how... without knowing your data I couldn't say.

Comment: can i just delete the highlighted row without indicating any specific type of value before it deletes the row?

Comment: What is the primary key of the `attendance` table?

Comment: I have not set one for the attendance table

Comment: Then how can you possibly expect to be able to single out a particular row?

Comment: but if i set it to primary key then i would not be able to enter multiple rows of records with the same employeeID, unless there is a way round it.

Comment: The `employeeID` doesn't have to be the primary key.  You can create a new, auto-increment PK.  It doesn't have to hold any meaning for the user.  It just exists so that the database can distinguish between rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datagridview needs a column with the `attendance` table's primary key.  It can be a hidden (non-visible) column if you don't want the user to see it.

Without a primary key (or a unique constraint, but let's use the PK for simplicity's sake), there is no way for the database to ensure that you are referring to a single, specific row.

Then, you need to change the following lines in your VB code:

```
Dim myPrimaryKey As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("PrimaryKeyColumnName").Value
```

Change your delete statement as well:

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM attendance WHERE AttendancePK=" & myPrimaryKey
```

Comment: OK great, i got it to work now but how do i remove the column with the primary key that i don't want the user to see?

Comment: Set its `Visible` property to false.

Comment: i used sql to enter in the table into datagrid. I just uploaded the code

Comment: Going from memory here, but try `Me.DataGridView1.Columns("PrimaryKeyColumnName").Visible = False`.  Or you can just set it in the designer, assuming that the columns aren't auto-generated.

Comment: i can't seem to find and change it to Me.DataGridView1.Columns("PrimaryKeyColumnName").Visible = False..

Answer (score 0):

I just did the edits in place so you'll need more changes. If the case is your user has selected one row to delete.

The changes are marked with *****

Also, you test to see if cnn is connected on the way in. If you want to return with cnn still connected you'll have to set a flag to determine the state on exit.

```
Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    'check for the selected item in the list
    If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count =  1 Then   *****
            Dim intemployeeno As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("EmployeeID").Value
            'open connection if not already opened
            If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cnn.Open()
            End If
            'delete data
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            cmd.Connection = cnn
            'cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM attendance " & intemployeeno
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM attendance WHERE employeeID=" & intemployeeno
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cnn.Close()  *****  
            'refresh data
            Me.refreshdata()
            'Display pop up alert before deleting row of data
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Select 1 row before you hit Delete")
            'close connection
          '  cnn.Close()  *****

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Douglas is closer to the OP. Although I would guess you could get the ID# from the first selected row and execute the DELETE just once, then refresh the dataset. On the original SQL looks a bit scary - a mass delete from Attendance of all records with the given ID#. Is that what you want?

Comment: The problem isn't that multiple rows are selected; the problem is that SQL is deleting ALL of the rows with that particular `employeeID`.  It isn't unique.